# How to store spark pair rdd as file into HDFS ?

Tags: hdfs, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, rdd, apache-kafka-connect

**Hi, I created a kafka topic with 3 partitions and 2 replicas. I try to publish messages/records from kafka to spark streaming (for some process), then store data into HDFS. I tried to store pair RDD as text file, but is not working.**

this code is not working,

```
JavaPairInputDStream<String, String> directKafkaStream = KafkaUtils
                .createDirectStream(ssc, String.class, String.class,
                        StringDecoder.class, StringDecoder.class, kafkaParams,
                        topics);
        directKafkaStream.foreachRDD(rdd -> {
                     if(!rdd.isEmpty()){
                         rdd.saveAsTextFile(path);
                     }
                     }
                );
```

console output:

```
17/01/09 17:25:39 INFO KafkaRDD: Computing topic filebeat, partition 1 offsets 20 -> 32
17/01/09 17:25:39 INFO VerifiableProperties: Verifying properties
17/01/09 17:25:39 INFO VerifiableProperties: Property group.id is overridden to 
17/01/09 17:25:39 INFO VerifiableProperties: Property zookeeper.connect is overridden to localhost:2181
17/01/09 17:25:39 INFO KafkaRDD: Computing topic filebeat, partition 0 offsets 22 -> 34
17/01/09 17:25:39 INFO VerifiableProperties: Verifying properties
17/01/09 17:25:39 INFO VerifiableProperties: Property group.id is overridden to 
17/01/09 17:25:39 INFO VerifiableProperties: Property zookeeper.connect is overridden to localhost:2181
17/01/09 17:25:40 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1483979140000 ms
17/01/09 17:25:40 ERROR Utils: Aborting task
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/kafka/common/message/KafkaLZ4BlockOutputStream
    at kafka.message.ByteBufferMessageSet$.decompress(ByteBufferMessageSet.scala:65)
    at kafka.message.ByteBufferMessageSet$$anon$1.makeNextOuter(ByteBufferMessageSet.scala:179)
    at kafka.message.ByteBufferMessageSet$$anon$1.makeNext(ByteBufferMessageSet.scala:192)
    at kafka.message.ByteBufferMessageSet$$anon$1.makeNext(ByteBufferMessageSet.scala:146)
    at kafka.utils.IteratorTemplate.maybeComputeNext(IteratorTemplate.scala:66)
    at kafka.utils.IteratorTemplate.hasNext(IteratorTemplate.scala:58)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$18.hasNext(Iterator.scala:764)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaRDD$KafkaRDDIterator.getNext(KafkaRDD.scala:211)
    at org.apache.spark.util.NextIterator.hasNext(NextIterator.scala:73)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$13$$anonfun$apply$7.apply$mcV$sp(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1203)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$13$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1203)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$13$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1203)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1325)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$13.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1211)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$13.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1190)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.kafka.common.message.KafkaLZ4BlockOutputStream
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 22 more
17/01/09 17:25:40 ERROR Utils: Aborting task
```

In fact my pom.xml

```html
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: The error is right there: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/kafka/common/message/KafkaLZ4BlockOutputStream
`. Your classpath is missing the kafka clients jar.

Comment: Thanks, I resolved my problems. In effect, I change kafka version to 0.8.2.1 which is stable and compatible with spark streaming.